# Can google's firebase work with a java desktop application?

Tags: java, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an iOS app using firebase, but I also want to create a java desktop application that accesses the same realtime database that the app uses. Is this possible to do? I feel as if this should be able to work because firebase works for Android apps which are written in Java. If this is possible, please give some details on how to go about doing this. Also, I am asking this in regards to the new and revamped firebase website that Google just recently announced.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has a [server SDK for Java](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#authenticate-with-admin-privileges) that should also work in a desktop Java application.  The code is very similar to the Android Firebase code so you'll see familiar classes like `DatabaseReference` or `ValueEventListener`.

Comment: Shipping the server credentials won't be a nice idea imo.