# Get credentials for desktop Java SE Firebase project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-console

I'm trying to access a Firebase database in desktop (non-Android) Java, and can't find where to download the dedifferentiate credentials JSON to initialise the API. There's an option to get started for Android, but that requires putting in an app name and fully-qualified identifier, which isn't applicable for a desktop project. Is there another way of obtaining this file? Or is there an alternative initialisation option?

Comment: If you're creating an administrative app, you should start with the [Firebase Admin SDK for Java](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315549/can-googles-firebase-work-with-a-java-desktop-application

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what's an administrative app? I just want to read and write from the database in the 'normal' firebase way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [firebase-talk mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/NLm5PfHWNZg):

> We currently don't have an SDK that is intended for Java desktop apps. We do have a [Java server SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup), but it requires a service account which is not secure to include in a desktop app. Your options are to either use the [Realtime Database's REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) or communicating with Firebase via your own custom server using the Java server SDK.
>
> We are not actively working on building an SDK for Java desktop apps. However, if others out there would like to see this, please chime in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/NLm5PfHWNZg).

Comment: Just to add: Unfortunately the REST API only supports standard read access or it needs an firebase ID token, to authenticate and do writes on rules guarded nodes. But gathering the token is not possible via rest, so the REST API can't be used fully to write a java se application against firebase.

Comment: You'll need to generate an access token client-side. The easiest way to do this is with one of the admin SDKs, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#generate_an_access_token. You can either run this on your own server (e.g. with the Java Admin SDK to generate the tokens), or on Cloud Functions (using the Node.js Admin SDK). If you're having trouble implementing this, I suggest posting a new question.

Comment: Yeah this way I'll bypass all database rules. That is not what I wanted to say. I'd like to have an firebase ID token, to gather read/write access as a user via rest calls with auth=[token] postfix. With the admin token, I'll will bypass any rules restrictions. I just wanted to add this piece of information to your answer.

Comment: The Admin SDK itself runs with administrative privileges and indeed bypasses security rules. But you can **generate** regular user token with the Admin SDK.

Comment: Thank you! But as far as I know the admin sdk generates custom tokens and the rest API expects firebase ID token, don't they?