# Can I use Firebase with java desktop app?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, desktop-application

I'm developing a java desktop POS System, and I want all the users to be connected together with firebase.
So, can I use Google Firebase with a Java desktop application?

Answer (score 4):

There is no official SDK for using Firebase in client-side Java applications.

You can use some Firebase products through their [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/), but you'll have to write your own client-side access code for that.

There is an official Firebase Admin SDK for use in Java applications. But this SDK grants the users of the application full administrative access to your Firebase project, so it should not be used in Java applications that you share with regular (non-administrative) users.

Also see:

- [Can google's firebase(Real-time database) work with a java desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48820863/can-googles-firebasereal-time-database-work-with-a-java-desktop-application)
- [Can google's firebase work with a java desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37315980)
- [Get credentials for desktop Java SE Firebase project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822084/get-credentials-for-desktop-java-se-firebase-project)

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely round-about. But you can use firebase with desktop using outbound HTTP connections and firebase functions. Just make sure you set up your own client api key or else anyone can mess with your firebase!